# Kafka Message is not consumed by consumer after multiple try same message is consumed and processed

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I am using the spring application to post the JSON payload to the Kafka topic. The message has been sent by the producer end, but the consumer is not processing the message the first time. After multiple retries, the same message has been processed

Tying to send the Kafka message through the producer and I am excepting the same message to be consumed by the Kafka consumer

Kafka version 2.13

**Producer**

```
KafkaTemplate<String, Object> kafkaTemplate;

    public void producer(JsonPayload payLoad) {
    try{
        kafkaTemplate.send(kafkaTopic, payLoad);
    }catch(Exception e){
        throw e;
    }
    return;
}
```

**Consumer**

```
@KafkaListener(topics = "${kafka.topics")
public void Listener(Object payLoad) {
    if(payLoad != null) {
        try {
                service.processPayload(payLoad);
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You don't _have_ to [show us the code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) you're running. But if you choose to not reveal the code and its output, that will rather impact the ability of SO contributors to understand, diagnose, and repair your issue.